# How to access the webpack config with the new Loader API?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

My loader ([external-svg-sprite-loader](https://github.com/karify/external-svg-sprite-loader)) requires access to the option `output.publicPath` defined in the webpack configuration file. According to webpack 2 [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/) the `this.options` property in the Loader API was deprecated, which means at some point my loader will no longer work. Is there another way of accessing this value or of generating a URL based on the value of `output.publicPath`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the compile time variable `__webpack_public_path__`.

Answer (score 1):

The webpack2 docs talk about using the [LoaderOptionsPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/loader-options-plugin/) to pass options to your loader context.  So in this case, for `options.output.publicPath` one could add this to their webpack plugins config:

```
new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
  test: /\.svg$/,
  options: {
    output: {
      publicPath: options.publicPath,
    },
  },
}));
```

see also [what's new in webpack2](https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7#loader-options--minimize)